# Time validation (From Time to To Time)

Tags: html, angular, validation

I have used [min] for validation of time(From Time to To Time) where drop time must be greater than Pickup time.

My HTML code is shown below

```html
<form #addForm="ngForm" required autocomplete="off">
  <mat-card>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Pickup Time</th>
          <th>Drop Time</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody ngModelGroup="stageForm">
        <tr *ngFor="let item of stageListData;">
          <td class="col-md-1">
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
              <input matInput [(ngModel)]="item.pickupTime" name="pickupTime" type="time"
                autocomplete="off" [disabled]="FieldReadonly" required>
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
          <td class="col-md-1">
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
              <input matInput [(ngModel)]="item.dropTime" name="dropTime" [min]="item.pickupTime"
                 type="time" autocomplete="off" [disabled]="FieldReadonly" required>
              <mat-error *ngIf="addForm.controls['dropTime']?.errors?.required">
                {{labels.value}}
              </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        <tr>
      <tbody>
    </table>
  <mat-card>
</form>
```

But it is not validating. Can anyone suggest the solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/JavaScript">
function validateHhMm(inputField) {
    var isValid = /^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$/.test(inputField.value);

    if (isValid) {
        inputField.style.backgroundColor = '#bfa';
    } else {
        inputField.style.backgroundColor = '#fba';
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

```
<FORM METHOD="POST">
<input type="text" onchange="validateHhMm(this);" />
```

used this code....

Comment: Follow this Link :- https://code-maze.com/angular-material-form-validation/